# Ajax servlet send-recive don't working

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have a HTML and a JavaServlet page (jobSeeker.html and jobSeekerServlet.java). I try to send data to servlet, but it does not working, and I have no idea why. Please help me. Here is me code:
jobSeeker.html

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="defaultScripts.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function sendData(){
            var sendInfo = {
                searchText:document.getElementById("txtSearch")
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'jobSeekerServlet',
                data: sendInfo, 
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/.json',
                success: function(data) { 
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>

   <form name="jobSeekersForm" method="post" id="jobSeekersForm">
       <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Keresés" onkeyup="sendData()"><br><br>
```

jobSeekerServlet.java:

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
       String text = "some text";
       response.setContentType("text/plain");
       response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       response.getWriter().write(text);  
    }
}
```

(I also write this code into the doPost method.)

Comment: explain what is not working

Comment: the "alert(data)" row does othing, so I think, I get back nothing from server side.

Comment: Can you add your web.xml or @Webservlet mapping code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check  servlet mapping is correctly written in web.xml

please refer this url [click here](http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-send-receive-json-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: My web.xml was generated by Netbeans. I don't see any error in this file.

Comment: you go through the link which i share and check

Comment: @user3607058, That's the link you need to read, propably you missed the json provider like jackson, gson, etc.